# Nano Editor on Remote Server broken after OS X Lion Upgrade on Local

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I am having a problem with my remote servers. I typically use the nano editor to modify files but suddenly after installing OS X lion on my local pc the editor seems broken. After some time suddenly the cursor seems randomly jumping around (it stays at the same position), text is written over other text. That makes it impossibile to do any text editing.

I have the same issue on two Macs.

I am using several aliases in /etc/bashrc. Could that be the issue?

Comment: What OS is remote? What terminal program you use?

Comment: CentOS. I am using the default Mac OS Terminal.

Comment: Try to change the TERM variable of remote system.